# How to set Background Color for Material3 TabRow in Android Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I try to set the background color for the Material 3 Card in Android Jetpack Compose, using the backgroundColor parameter, "colors" also. modifier doesn't work. The color of the tab row elements is reddish, but I need white. Thanks

implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Bfd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEW5r.png)

```
fun TabbedContent() {
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Black),

            ) {
            TabRow(

                selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
                ),
                indicator = { tabPositions ->
                    TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                        color = Color(3, 169, 244),
                        modifier = Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedTabIndex])
                    )
                },
```

Cannot find a parameter with this name: backgroundColor && Cannot find a parameter with this name: colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `TabRow` background color Using `containerColor` attribute for Material3.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRow
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults.tabIndicatorOffset
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableIntStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

@Composable
fun Ex18() {
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Black),

            ) {
            TabRow(
                selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White),
                containerColor = Color.White,
                indicator = { tabPositions ->
                    TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                        color = Color(3, 169, 244),
                        modifier = Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedTabIndex])
                    )
                },
                tabs = {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro, haha, 2 hours couldn't decide

Comment: sometimes some easy things also consume more time